# How to filter Multivalue controls values?

Tags: tfs

I have multivalue control and it is working fine. Now I want this control to filter on basis of another field value.

For eg :

Multi Value Control - Select Applications
Options - App1 High, App2 Low, App1 Low, App2 High

Second Control - Select Severity
Options - High, Low

If I select severity as High then MV control should show only App1 High and App2 High, same with selecting Low option.

Please suggest.

TFS Azure DevOps Template and Extensions